# Angular ngChecked by default true, prevents change/click event?

Tags: angularjs, checkbox

I want to understand the behavior of the below code segment.

**Expected :**

When you click on a check box it should add an attribute in `myData` (`val3`/`val4`) with the  value same as the checkbox's.

**Actual :**

When you check the 2nd check box its working fine, but when you uncheck the 1st, it does not insert `val3` with `false` value. It only inserts `val3` when checked again.

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('MyController', ['$scope',
    function($scope) {
      $scope.myData = {
        val1: true,
        val2: false
      };
    }
  ]);
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <form ng-controller="MyController">
    MyData : 
    {{myData}}<br/>
    <label>Val1:
      <input type="checkbox" 
             ng-checked="myData.val1" 
             ng-model="myData.val3">
    </label><br/>
    <label>Val2:
      <input type="checkbox" 
             ng-checked="myData.val2" 
             ng-model="myData.val4">
    </label><br/>

    val1 = {{myData.val1}}<br/>
    val2 = {{myData.val2}}<br/>
    val3 = {{myData.val3}}<br/>
    val4 = {{myData.val4}}<br/>
  </form>
</div>
```

Why such a behavior ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The official documentation explicitly states to avoid using ng-checked with ng-model. [Link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChecked)

> Note that this directive should not be used together with ngModel, as this can lead to unexpected behavior.
>
> A special directive is necessary because we cannot use interpolation
>   inside the checked attribute. See the interpolation guide for more
>   info.

I wound suggest doing it this way - without separating the checkbox state and the model.

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('MyController', ['$scope',
    function($scope) {
      $scope.myData = {
        val1: true,
        val2: false
      };
    }
  ]);
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <form ng-controller="MyController">
    MyData : 
    {{myData}}<br/>
    <label>Val1:
      <input type="checkbox" 
             ng-model="myData.val1">
    </label><br/>
    <label>Val2:
      <input type="checkbox" 
             ng-model="myData.val2">
    </label><br/>

    val1 = {{myData.val1}}<br/>
    val2 = {{myData.val2}}<br/>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: How can I use ngChange?

Comment: actually reading through your code I realized you don't need ng-change at all. I will add an example

Comment: IMHO The example that you gave is not correct. As you xan see in my question.. I want to set val3 and val4 on any change of radios not val1 and val2. Val1 and 2 acts as default values and val3 and 4 are the actual ones. How can i achieve that without using ngChange and ngModel?